# Как полностью удалить учетку Microsoft Outlook из системы?

Tags: windows, outlook

Заходил из Windows 10 в приложение Почта, добавлял свою учетную запись. Делал это на один раз. Вышел из своей учетки и она как-будто удалилась. Но если я нажимаю кнопку "Добавить учетную запись" то предлагает сразу мою учетку и входит в нее без запроса пароля.

Помогите пожалуйста мне полностью удалить учетку Microsoft из винды10.

*Компьютер рабочий и с него сидит большое количество людей, чья добросовествность под вопросом. Если бы я знал, что windows так хорошо запоминает учетки и не дaет их так просто удалять, не стал бы связываться.*

Answer (score 4):

Пуск, Электронная почта и учетные записи, Клик на свою учетку, Управление, удалить, ниже есть еще учетка(учетные записи используемые другими приложениями), кликнуть на нее, удалить.